# Differentiate between access denied & login failure

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a monitoring component which monitors every windows objects in a network. I am using WMI & Powershell for that purpose. I will be extracting the connection exceptions to identify what kind of exceptions are coming for each object. For example...

```
if (exceptionMessage.ToLower().Contains("access is denied."))
{
    // Returns as access denied
}
else if (exceptionMessage.ToLower().Contains("the rpc server is unavailable."))
{
    // Returns as host unavailable
}
else if (exceptionMessage.ToLower().Contains("this operation would create an incorrectly structured document."))
{
    // Returns the exception
}
else
{
    // Returns as Login failure
}
```

But in most cases, even if I give invalid credentials, i am getting only "Access Denied", not "Login failed".

Can anyone explain why this is happening. How we can differentiate between "Access denied" and "Login failed".

Any helpful information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Is your script misinterpreting the error message, or is the error message not what you expect? What command are you issuing that generates the error message?

Comment: I just want to know the situations where "Access denied" & "Login Failed" is coming

Comment: Actually I am trying to connect to a windows object and interprets the exception message to find out whether the object status is "Host unavailable", "Access Denied" or "Login failed"

Answer (score 0):

user should already have to get access privillage  for whatever you want access.so the user account

have to previously create and give to access authority.if does not add then it will show the

"Access Denined".

User already have account means,after they will enter wrong login information then it will show

"login failed"

Comment: In my case, I have tried with an invalid user & a wrong password; In both cases, I am getting "access denied" exception. What I expect is "Login Failed" when I give wrong password.